# Binary decision tree model when the proportion of one of the labels is almost null

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I want to make a decision tree with two options to predict; "YES" or "NO". The dataset I am working with has 99% of "YES" answers and only 1% of "NO" answers. As I ran the model, the score is up to 97% of accuracy.

Is it a valid model or are there any considerations to take into account when working with this kind of unbalanced proportions?

I am afraid that because of the large amount of "YES" data, the model is very accurate by saying the answer to everything is "YES". The "NO"s are very important to this use of case, in fact, that is what we want to identify

Comment: This is the inherent problem with using accuracy as a metric with imbalanced data. Look at Precision, Recall, and F1 scores as they may relate to your use case. Beyond that, there are dozens of ways to handle imbalanced data, so the question is likely too broad for this site, without a specific question with a [mcve]

Comment: Obviously, your "accuracy" metric does not match what you see as quality of your model.  Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) with other metrics.

Comment: That's so useful! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your benchmark has to be 99%. Because having a model that uses a basic average to predict (resulting in predicting "YES" always), will have a 99% accuracy. These cases are better evaluated by using roc or auroc instead of accuracy. When working with extremely unbalanced data, most of the times it is a rule of thumb to benchmark on the proportion of the data belonging to the dominant class.